# How to send input data value into custom directive in angular-2?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am experimenting upon custom directives of angular-2 basic where I want to parse an input value in my custom directive.

Lets have a look.

I have an app component called app.component.ts. Where I have taken an input field.

```
<input [(ngModel)] = "myInput"/>
```

Next I build a custom directive name custom.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer} from '@angular/core';

@Directive ({
  selector : '[customDir]'
})
export class CustomDirective{
  constructor(private el : ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer){ }
}
```

Now I would like to input anything  in "app.component.ts and parse it in my custom directive by which I can simply print it in console..

Lets re modify my code...

```
<app.component.ts>
<input [(ngModel)] = "myInput" [customDir] = "myInput"/> 
<custom.directive.ts>
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive ({
  selector : '[customDir]'
})

export class CustomDirective{
  @Input('customDir') myInput : any;
  constructor(private el : ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer){ }
     console.log(this.myInput);
  }
```

But it is not working properly. Printing un define..

My Concern is...

1... How I parse the data just against the each key press..?

Please suggest me anyone...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Directive ({
  selector : '[customDir]',
  exportAs: 'customDir' // <<<=== added
})
export class CustomDirective{
  myInput : any;
}
```

and use it like

```
<input customDir #customDir="customDir" [(ngModel)]="myInputInApp" (ngModelChange)="customDir.myInput = $event"/>
```

The first `customDir` is to get the directive applied at all.

`#customDir="customDir"` is to create a template variable that has a reference to the directive (requires `exportAs`)

`[(ngModel)]="customDir.myInput"` binds to the directive referenced by the template variable `#customDir` and its property `input`. `@Input()` is not required for this case because it's not Angular binding that is used here.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/V3Pdesd44SqSRO91YqZo?p=preview)

This should work as well and is easier to use:

```
@Directive ({
  selector : '[customDir]',
})
export class CustomDirective{

  @HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])
  onModelChange(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

```
<input customDir [(ngModel)]="someOtherProp"/>
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/StyRBbBATelYAt9RS70h?p=preview)

Comment: I want to print against each key pressing. Above code is not working.. Whatever I will enter by keyboard, it will shown in console using custom directives.

Comment: Do you have a `myInput` property in `AppComponent`?